# Direct analogue of a 2D graph of a function in 3D space

Tags: functions

I am looking for an explanation/justification on the idea of direct "extension" of a scalar 1 variable function (which can be represented as a 2D graph, by that I mean of course y wrt x, i.e. dependent vs independent var.)to a scalar 2 variable function (which is represented as a surface in 3D space).

In 1D it is simple : $y=f(x)$, for example, i'll take the sine function: $y = sin(x)$.

However in 2D, (note even talking about N-D) there could be many possibilities: $z=sin(x+y)$, or $z=sin(x)+sin(y)$, or ...

But it seems that the direct "analogue" as I call it (dont know how to call it in fact?) is:

$z=f(x,y)=sin(\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)})$

Or more generally:
$z=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$

For any function f in general.

I think it comes from the Pythagorean theorem since the argument inside the the function, e.g. sin(), in my example, is then the hypothenuse of a right triangle formed by x and y coords.

I.e., if that's correct, then it means that generalizing to 2D, we need to use the Pythagorean theorem.  And probably even so for ND with the argument  of f being $\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2)}$ I would imagine?  although it is not drawable.

OK but  just  mentionning the Pythagorean theorem...that isn't really a justification in itself...

Could someone go into the details and explain it/justify it etc.?

P.S.
Since I dont know /didn't find the appropriate keywords to find such an explanation anywhere ... so that's why I ask it here...

Comment: You’ve described what’s known as a surface of rotation, but that’s not the only way to extend a function of one variable to $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Interesting, please can you develop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a real-valued function of a vector, or in other words, of several variables. For one variable, there's only one way to evaluate such a function, since there's just one component. However, when you have more than one component, there may be many ways to use the same function on the same vector. For example, suppose we have the function $f:\mathrm R\to\mathrm R$ defined by $f(x)=\sin x,$ where $x\in\mathrm R,$ then a direct analogue in two dimensions should be a function $f:\mathrm R^2\to\mathrm R$ defined by $f(x,y)=\sin(x,y).$ But $\sin(x,y)$ may be defined in anyway, since the $\sin$ is defined only on real numbers. So we still need to specify directly how we want the sine to act on the vector $(x,y),$ via acting on a real value defined by this vector. That is, we have to actually let the sine act on some other real-valued function $g(x,y)$ before we can fix $f.$ One way may be to use the euclidean norm of $(x,y),$ as you've done. But there are infinitely many ways to generate unique real numbers for every pair $(x,y).$ Another might be to  $e^x-e^{-y},$ etc.

In summary, when dealing with higher-dimensional analogues of real functions over domains of of the real line, there often has to be a composition with a real-valued function of such variables, which can happen in several ways, since the original functions were defined only for real numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. And I guess the same applies for the multivariate Gaussian distribution w.r.t. the univariate one, of course, since the multiv. Gauss. is the 1D one but with a (x,y) vector as argument. But it seems that they have chosen the euclidean norm as g(x,y) since for the $X,Y \sim N([0 , 0],\mathbb{I}_2)$ we have $e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ (without normalization factors etc.) which comes from like $e^{-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2}$, since 1D gauss. $\sim N(0,1), e^{-x^2}$, yes?

Comment: @Machupicchu The same works for any multivariate real function conceived of as a direct extension of some single variable analogue, but it need not be. Whatever functions we use depends on what we want them to do. I confess I know little about probability and statistics, so I can't answer your last question.

Comment: So, in summary, things begin to get messier when going > 1D !

Comment: @Machupicchu I like to think of it as things getting more interesting! ;)

Comment: yes its true, of course !

Comment: If you want to check another question I have here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616416/development-of-the-inverse-fourier-transform-to-show-that-complex-exponentials-c

Answer (score 1):

If you transform your Cartesian $(x,y,z)$ coordinates to cylindrical $(r,\theta,z)$ coordinates, then $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^y}$ at every point and your surface has the function $z = \sin(r)$ for $r \geq 0.$

Basically what you have done is to take part of the sine function (namely, $\sin(x)$ where $x \geq 0,$ excluding all the parts where $x < 0$) and rotate it around the origin of your coordinate system to form a surface of rotation.

There are some important qualitative differences between the sine function and this surface of rotation.
The surface of rotation is differentiable everywhere *except* at $(x,y)=(0,0),$
but the one-dimensional sine function is differentiable everywhere with no exceptions.
The one-dimensional sine function can be translated (moved sideways) a distance $2\pi$ along the $x$ axis and you get the exact same function again.
The surface of rotation can be rotated around the origin (but not any other point) to get the exact same surface;
but if you translate it, no matter by what amount in what direction you will get a different function.

There is a technique called Fourier analysis which (in one of its forms)
uses functions of the form $\sin(x),$ $\cos(x),$ $\sin(2x),$ $\cos(2x),$ etc.
A two-dimensional version of this might have functions
$\sin(x),$ $\cos(x),$ $\sin(y),$ $\cos(y),$ $\sin(x)\cos(y),$ $\sin(x)\sin(y),$
$\sin(2x),$ $\sin(2y)$, $\sin(2x)\cos(y),$ $\cos(x)\sin(2y),$ and so forth.

Any of the two-variable functions defined in the previous paragraph can be translated a distance $2\pi$ parallel to either the $x$ or $y$ axis and you get the exact same function again.
But if you translate by $2\pi$ in another direction you do not get the same function.
You could translate by $2\sqrt2\pi$ in a direction parallel to the line $y=x$, $z=0$ and get the same function. But $2\sqrt2\pi \neq 2\pi,$
so the properties of such a function are tied to a particular choice of orientation of the $x$ and $y$ axes, unlike your surface of rotation.

So it is hard to come up with an analogous function that will be the two-dimensional equivalent of the sine function in every way. I don't think it can be done perfectly; I think you will always have to choose some desirable properties and abandon others.

Comment: ok, maybe the last question in my comment below is for you?

Comment: A Gaussian has a center already and reflective symmetry, which is a little easier to extend to two dimensions. But the notation $N([0 , 0],\mathbb{I}_2)$ is only _one_ possible two-dimensional Gaussian from a family described by $\sim N([a, b],M$ where $a$ and $b$ are any real numbers and $M$ is a $2\times2$ real matrix. By setting $M=\mathbb I_2$ we ensure rotational symmetry around $(a,b),$ but other matrices can "stretch" the function in any direction, and then the exponent will not be simply $x^2+y^2.$

Comment: yes I know that in the general formula you have a covariance matrix which can be anything

Comment: Anyway the distribution $N([0 , 0],\mathbb{I}_2)$ is "standard" in much the same way that $N(0,1)$ is, and one of its nice properties happens to be rotational symmetry around the origin, which goes hand in hand with being a function of $x^2 + y^2.$ Essentially, in order to have rotational symmetry we end up using the Euclidean norm, and if we use the Euclidean norm we get rotational symmetry.

Comment: hum ok rotational symmetry. interesting

Comment: In case you're interested to check my new question about Fourier transforms here :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616416/development-of-the-inverse-fourier-transform-to-show-that-complex-exponentials-c