# Development of the inverse Fourier transform to show that complex exponentials cancel each other

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

When considering the inverse Fourier transform of a (1D) signal $x(t)$ :

$x(t) = \int{X(f)e^{j2\pi ft}df}$

considering that the forward transform to get the Fourier transform coefficients, denoted with capital X, and I use $f$ for frequency, is:

$ X(f) = \int{x(t)e^{-j2\pi f t}dt} $

(I didn't put any bounds on the integrals since it's not really important here I guess.)

It seems to make sense (sort of intuitively) that one can fall back to the original function because the basis vectors (complex exponentials) cancel each other with the exponent rule of multiplication $a^na^m=a^{n+m}$, - (that is the intuition that I have, even though I'm not 100% sure, but would be surprised otherwise) - more precisely I am tempted to write:

$x(t) = \int{ (\int{x(t)e^{-j2\pi f t}dt})e^{j2\pi f t} df}$

It seems very nice to think that there would be some way of rewriting this (last) integral in order to have the complex exponents cancel each other, i.e.: $e^{-j2\pi f t}e^{j2\pi f t} = e^{-j2\pi f t + j2\pi f t} = e^{0} = 1$ , therefore leaving the integral with just $\int{x(t)dt}$ and since there always is a normalization factor (perhaps 1/length(x)) then x is recovered.

Can someone derive this step by step please, if it is possible to derive it from that last formula? That would be very interesting to gain a better understanding of the inverse Fourier transform.

**As it has been mentioned in the comments, it might be too complex to demonstrate here in fact. However, could someone confirm if the intuition that the $e^{-j...}$ and $e^{j...}$ in fact cancel each other resulting in $e^0 = 1$ at some point and therefore allows the recovery of the function ? (I mean can someone confirm that with possibly a mathematical argument but not with a full demo since it's too complex most likely)**

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem

Comment: Thanks, I ve seen it yes but I don't completely understand they're notation and I would like q more detailed development.

Comment: It would be nice if someone could develop it in a more comprehensible way, with the notation that I'm using, which is quite a common notation in fact (used in many university lectures)

Comment: In Math books one writes $i$ for your $j$ and the $2\pi$ in your definition of FT is omitted. Also a multiplicative factor is often present. So by no means are your notations standard. Perhaps your notations are from Physics.

Comment: Ok yes it's from a professor who is also from an electrical engineering background but details like 2pi and i or j are not the problem: on the wiki site they use x and y for example whereas for me it should be the same variable e.g. t in my notation, and other things... anyway I would like an understandable way to show how to rearrange the integrals to show that the exp cancel each other .... or is it in fact very complicated to do ?

Comment: They don't just cancel out easily. Inversion theorem is quite complicated. The book I like best is Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.

Comment: and for example, in the wiki paragraph "Two-sided inverse" the development is not detailed enough (for me): they still have these 2 variables x and y ! And they're change of variables zeta and xi (I don't mind that they use greek letters) does not make sens to me (don't see why they introduce it)

Comment: Ok, I see. However, can you confirm (or not) that the "intuition" that the exp(i...) and exp(-i...) cancel out each other, and that it is the idea behind the inverse to allow to recover the function?

Comment: here is the intuition of the inverse Fourier Transform ... start with a list of frequencies where each freq has a magnitude and phase shift ... now for each frequency create an oscillator generating a sin curve at that freq with its max/min driven by its magnitude using its offset ... do this for each freq in original list ... now synthesize a single output curve where the curve height at a point in time is the average of all oscillators at that same point in time ... this synthesized output curve is the time domain representation of the frequency domain of your original list of frequencies

Comment: I know that the intuition is that any signal can be reconstructed by a linear combination of pure sine waves,  the Fourier basis vectors, that's not my question. My question is specifically about the exp(-j..) and exp(+j..) . I know that they come from the (beautiful)Euler's formula exp(jx)=cosx+jsinx. Question,  again is : can we or can we not consider that at some point -in a  possibly very complex derivation - consider that the exp(j..) and exp(-j..) can be written in such a way that they multiply each other and therefore cancels out =1 and therefore results on 1*originalSignal ?!

Comment: (after dividing the integral by a scaling factor but that's detail)